# Error checking delimited fscanf

Tags: c, scanf, csv

I am trying to use fscanf to read a file that is colon delimited and take out certain information. I am using a function to do this and am having issues with some of the error checking. The function is

```
int
print_name_number(FILE *input, FILE *output)
{
    char name[24];
    char address[50];
    char phone[50];
    char other[50];
    char age[50];

    while (fscanf(input, "%24[^:]:%50[^:]:%50[^:]:%50[^:]:%50s[^:]"
          , name, address, phone, other, age) != EOF)   
    fprintf(output, "%s %-24s\n", name, phone);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which works for now however, I am looking for a way to check if the line read is actually of the format "name second:address:phone:other:age". I have tried checking if the fscanf is equal to 5 but if less than 5 things are read in fscanf just keeps trying to read things in. Is there a way to cause scanf to stop if only "name:" is entered or something like that?

Thanks in advance for any and all help.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fscanf` won't stop until (a) the input format has been completely read, (b) the input fails to match the expected format (e.g. `scanf("%d")` with alphabetic characters in the buffer) or (c) the end-of-file is reached. Thus, if your `input` file is connected to a terminal, and you typed `name:` expecting `fscanf` to quit, you will find that it just hangs waiting for you to finish.

Perhaps you want to use `fgets` instead, to read a single line of input - that way, the input reading will stop once a newline is encountered.

Comment: This is wrong. It **does** return `EOF`  on input failure. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p16. On most systems, this just happens to equal `-1`.